# Turning onClick dispatchEvent into an Auto Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, revolution-slider

I have a specific code that comes from Revolution Slider. Right now, if you click on this, it will popup like I need. But what I need it to do is auto popup once someone comes to the site. Essentially turning this into an auto click. How could I change this code in order to make it happen? You can see the code below.

You can also see the code working here: https://ae32d5d93a.nxcli.net/

```
<button id="clickMe" onclick="document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2')); return false">Auto Popup</button>
```

EDIT:

So I added it into a Magento 2 CMS Page and I am calling out the .js esstentionally. That part is working, as you can see the link grabs the javascript you sent me.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::popup.phtml"}}
```

https://ae32d5d93a.nxcli.net/static/version1645632931/frontend/Freshley/ultimo_child/en_US/js/popup.js

Comment: Just call the dispatchEvent on document ready or window load?

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

#### You can do a couple of things to achieve this.

---

1. You add the `onclick` function in the body `onload` event. For example, something like this should work:

```html
<body onload="document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2')); return false">
```

2. You can use javascript and run this in the `window.onload` function. See below for an example:

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2'));
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

3. This is my least recommended one. You can have the button and then use javascript to click it automatically. See the code below to see how to do this:


   **HTML:**

```html
<button id="clickMe" onclick="document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2')); return false">Auto Popup</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const button = document.getElementById('clickMe');
    button.click();
};
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, but that didn't seem to work. I added in the javascript option into the page. This is running on Magento 2 by the way. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I added what I did in order to get your code working to my original post. You'll see it's grabbing the code just fine, but it doesn't seem to take.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is there an error?

Comment: Oh no there is no error, but the auto popup is not working. https://ae32d5d93a.nxcli.net/ -- Go here and you will see that nothing auto pops up. But the code is inside the source.

Comment: Maybe try using solution 1, change your body tag to `<body onload="document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2')); return false">` and see if it works.

Comment: I tried that as well. Same deal.

Comment: Can I see the event code inside of `RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2`?

Comment: I posted an answer to show you what I can find. This is calling out from Revolution Slider, if that helps. I couldn't edit my original anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242338/discussion-between-k-k-desgins-and-corey).

Comment: I can't seem to find the issue for me, so hopefully, someone else can fix that.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<button id="clickMe">Auto Popup</button>
```

**CSS**

to hide the button

```
#clickMe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

to run the code when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when($('#clickMe').click()).done(() => {
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('RS_OPENMODAL_slider-2'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it is better way to use the onload event handler instead of click event.